# What is the minimum score after which all numbers can be scored?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods

> There are two types of scores present in a game 4,7. What is the minimum score after which all numbers can be scored?

I found the answer '18' without any accurate logic. This a math problem of Olympiad. Can you please give me a method?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this problem is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem ?

Comment: Actually that's hard for me to understand. Can you describe briefly in a way that I understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link posted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) by @Matti P gives a general method to solve it. If we are allowed score increments of $x$ and $y$, where $x$ and $y$ are coprime, then the maximum score which can't be obtained (the *Frobenius number*) is $xy - x - y$.

Putting in our values of $x=4$, $y=7$ gives 17. So any score greater than 17 can be obtained.

Answer (score -1):

According to Frobenius coin problem  this problem can be solved using the formula
 $xy-x-y$, where $x$ and $y$ are the value of coin or score. In your case $x=7$ and $y=9$
so your answer will be simply $63-7-9=47$.